# PHP version on phpinfo() older than the one on terminal

Tags: php, macos, apache

So I have a versioning problem with my php on my macOSX. The version showed on my terminal is correct and shows PHP 7.4.2. However, when I open up phpinfo() on my project I get [PHP 7.1.23](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SsVjS.png)

All the posts I keep finding on this subject is how the terminal is behind what is shown on phpinfo(), while I get the opposite. I installed php using homebrew since I needed to work with 7.4. However, I feel like php 7.1 was there prior to me installing 7.4, maybe it's the built-n php version on my mac?

Things I tried that did not work:

- Putting "export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.4/sbin:$PATH"" in my .bash_profile
- Removing and reinstalling php using homebrew
- Restarting Apache server thousands of times using "apachectl restart"
- Removed XCode and it's developer folder
- Cried in a corner in a fetal position

Anyone has other suggestions?

Comment: are you using mamp or install apache2 ?

Comment: Go to httpd.conf and make sure the correct version of PHP is loaded see `LoadModule`

Comment: 7.1.33 is what my macOS 10.14.6 shows for command line. You can see that with just `php -i` (same thing as doing phpinfo();). I suspect the apache config is looking to the original install. Homebrew may not be overwriting 7.1, but rather installing into a different location that apache didnt get informed about.

Comment: The version of PHP available from the command line has 100% nothing to do with the version of PHP loaded as a module. These are completely separate things. https://superuser.com/questions/969861/phpinfo-and-php-v-shows-different-version-of-php/1190483

Comment: Using apache2, I have LoadModule php7_module libexec/apache2/libphp7.so, php -i gives me php 7.4.2, how do I tell apache of the new location? @IncredibleHat

Comment: Try the answer given below ;)

Answer (score 3):

You have multiple versions of php installed and you should change the one used by apache. First you disable old module `sudo a2dismod php7.1`, then you enable new module `sudo a2enmod php7.4`.
Don't forget to restart apache after this operation.

Answer (score 0):

The answer posted by @vadim is technically right, but since a2enmod doesn't work on my mac, I needed to manually change it in the httpd.conf file. The php7_module was pointing to the 7.1 libphp7.so file. What I did was simply found the libphp7.so file installed by homebrew and change the location in the httpd.conf to point to that one.